# Strange error when using processing library from maven central in a sbt project

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, processing

I am trying to use the [processing java library](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.processing%7Cprocessing-complete%7C3.0b5%7Cpom) in a sbt project, so I added a line in build.sbt:

```
name := "testJson"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

//libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.processing" % "processing-complete" % "3.0b5"
```

I got an error:

```
[warn] 
[FAILED ] org.processing#processing-complete;3.0b5!processing-complete.jar: (0ms) 
[warn] ==== local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/.ivy2/local/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/jars/processing-complete.jar 
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/.activator/repository/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/jars/processing-complete.jar 
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/opt/activator-dist-1.3.5/repository/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/jars/processing-complete.jar 
[warn] ==== public: tried 
[warn] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/processing-complete-3.0b5.jar 
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried 
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/processing-complete-3.0b5.jar 
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried 
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/jars/processing-complete.jar 
[warn] 
[FAILED ] org.processing#processing-complete;3.0b5!processing-complete.jar(src): (0ms) 
[warn] ==== local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/.ivy2/local/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/srcs/processing-complete-sources.jar 
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/.activator/repository/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/srcs/processing-complete-sources.jar 
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/opt/activator-dist-1.3.5/repository/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/srcs/processing-complete-sources.jar 
[warn] ==== public: tried 
[warn] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/processing-complete-3.0b5-sources.jar 
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried 
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/processing-complete-3.0b5-sources.jar 
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried 
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/srcs/processing-complete-sources.jar 
[warn] 
[FAILED ] org.processing#processing-complete;3.0b5!processing-complete.jar(doc): (0ms) 
[warn] ==== local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/.ivy2/local/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/docs/processing-complete-javadoc.jar 
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/.activator/repository/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/docs/processing-complete-javadoc.jar 
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried 
[warn] /Users/kaiyin/opt/activator-dist-1.3.5/repository/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/docs/processing-complete-javadoc.jar 
[warn] ==== public: tried 
[warn] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/processing-complete-3.0b5-javadoc.jar 
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried 
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/processing-complete-3.0b5-javadoc.jar 
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried 
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.processing/processing-complete/3.0b5/docs/processing-complete-javadoc.jar 
[warn] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
[warn] :: FAILED DOWNLOADS :: 
[warn] :: ^ see resolution messages for details ^ :: 
[warn] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
[warn] :: org.processing#processing-complete;3.0b5!processing-complete.jar 
[warn] :: org.processing#processing-complete;3.0b5!processing-complete.jar(src) 
[warn] ::
```

What does it mean and how can it be solved?

Comment: you're probably missing the address of a resolver. it would help if you could post your build.sbt (and/or project/*.scala if you use more code for your build configuration)

Comment: on maven central `processing-complete` is a "Meta-build file to package Processing components.". That is it only consists of a `pom` file describing the modules that make a complete `processing` package. Is ivy not able to resolve meta packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the pom is there, the artifact isn't. See http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.processing . Here you can see what artifacts are available for which poms. I suspect the core artifact may be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You're not defining any resolver.

You might you want to try to add this line to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
```

Or check out this page that explains resolvers in more details: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html

Comment: As stated in the question, this is available at maven central. No additional resolver should be necessary, right?

Comment: This indeed eliminates the error, but when I try to `import processing.core._`, intellij says it can't be resolved.

Comment: this is probably unrelated and might be linked with how frequently intellij refreshes its caches. is the project building fine from the command line now?

Answer (score 1):

[The processing-complete module](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.processing%7Cprocessing-complete%7C3.0b5%7Cpom) is just a meta file describing the modules a processing.org offers. I would have expected that sbt/ivy would be able to resolve the modules defined in the *pom* file. However, if it does not (I didn't get sbt to download anything other then the *pom*), I'd suggest that you add the actual modules individually:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.processing" % "core" % "3.0b5"

libraryDependencies += "org.processing" % "net" % "3.0b5"

libraryDependencies += "org.processing" % "video" % "3.0b5"

libraryDependencies += "org.processing" % "serial" % "3.0b5"

libraryDependencies += "org.processing" % "pde" % "3.0b5"

libraryDependencies += "org.processing" % "pdf" % "3.0b5"
```

which works smoothly for me.